# How to Use the Get response in protractor script

Tags: javascript, protractor

I am wanted to get a field value from a index of ElasticSearch and compare it with Angular Kendo grid column value. For this I am using the EalsticSearch client and passing the Index, type and query string and from promise I am processing the results as per my req., my actual problem here is when I trying to use the function I wrote to get the value is not running thru protractor. its throwing Node Option error, need help how can i I use the result from ES.

I coded the following function and trying to get the date and id from ES to use in protractor script, but I am unable to:

```
var client = require('./connectES.js');  --> initializing local ES
var logger = require('./logger.js');

function getFileDate(indexData, typeData, bodyData) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, rejected) {
        client.search({  
            index:indexData,
            type:typeData,
            body:bodyData
        }).then(function(results){
            resolve(results);
        })
    })
}
var indexData = 'index';
var typeData = 'type';
var bodyData = 'query';
getFileDate(indexData, typeData, bodyData).then(function(results){
    var data = results.hits.hits;
    var values = [];
    for(var i = 0;i<data.length;i++){
        Object.values(data[i]).forEach(function(value){
            if(values.indexOf(value) == -1){
                values.push(value);
            }
        });
    }
    var sourceData = (values[4]);
    var dateValue = Object.values(sourceData);
    var Date = dateValue[0];
    var Id = dateValue[1];
    console.log('Date is: '+Date+' , ID is: '+Id);
});
```

How to use those ID and Date in Protractor script It block? Please help

Comment: Can you include the error you are receiving and can you tell us does `results.hits.hits` in the `getFileDate` function contain the expected value at the beginning of the function?

Comment: I am getting :Date is: undefined
ID is: undefined

Comment: You are getting both those in the same error stack trace? Is there a line number provided? I'm not sure how you could be getting that error based on the function you have provided. Providing a snippet of the actual error as it appears in the console is what could really be of assistance

Comment: Now I am facing different error, on protractor conf run :   E:\Projects\InReview\Project>protractor qa_conf.js

[14:12:47] E/launcher - Error: ConfigurationError: Missing node(s) option
    at new Client (E:\Projects\InReview\Project\node_modules\@elastic\elasticsearch\index.js:61:13)
[14:12:47] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 100

Answer (score 0):

This should be fairly straightforward. You just need to `resolve(dateValue)` instead of `results`.

Change your `getFileDate()` function to the following:

```
function getFileDate(indexData, typeData, bodyData) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, rejected) {
    client.search({
      index: indexData,
      type: typeData,
      body: bodyData
  }).then(function (results) {
      var data = results.hits.hits;
      var values = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        Object.values(data[i]).forEach(function (value) {
          if (values.indexOf(value) == -1) {
            values.push(value);
          }
        });
      }

      var sourceData = (values[4]);
      resolve(Object.values(sourceData));
    });
  });
}
```

And then in your test:

```
it('should do something', () => {
  var indexData = 'index';
  var typeData = 'type';
  var bodyData = 'query';

  getFileDate(indexData, typeData, bodyData).then((dateValue) => {
    expect(dateValue[0]).toEqual(someValue);
    expect(dateValue[1]).toEqual(someID);
  });

});
```